# R Plotly unable to remove trace 0 from bar chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

In my Shiny app, plotly produces a `trace 0` in the legend that imbalances my graph.

This is what the graph looks like (notice the `trace 0` in the legend).
[image]

However on clicking on `trace 0` in the legend, the graph returns back to normal

[image]

Is there a way of removing this `trace 0` from my plot completely?

Here is my code:

**1) My dataframe is first filtered inside a `reactive` function**

```
global_evolution=reactive({

  results_combined %>%
  filter(!is.na(SVM_LABEL_QOL) & SVM_LABEL_QOL=='QoL' & globalsegment==input$inp_pg1segment & Account==input$inp_pg1clientsfiltered & Date >=input$inp_pg1daterange[1] & Date <=input$inp_pg1daterange[2]) %>% #Input: Account
  select(Account,Date,SVM_LABEL_DIMENSION) %>%
  mutate(Month=month(as.Date(format(as.POSIXct(Date),format = "%d/%m/%Y"),"%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%
  select(Account,Month,SVM_LABEL_DIMENSION,-Date) %>%
  group_by(Month,SVM_LABEL_DIMENSION) %>%
  summarise(Monthly_Count=n()) %>%
  spread(SVM_LABEL_DIMENSION,Monthly_Count) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Month=month.abb[Month]) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))

})
```

**2) Then some more changes are made to the filtered dataframe inside another `reactive` function**

```
global_evolution_final=reactive({
global_evolution() %>%
  mutate(Month=factor(Month,levels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")))
})
```

3) Finally I use `plot_ly` to construct the bar chart. However the `trace 0` cannot be removed

```
output$pg1evolution <- renderPlotly({

colNames <- names(global_evolution_final())[-1] #Assuming Month is the first column

p <- plotly::plot_ly(data = global_evolution_final(), x = ~Month, type = "bar")

for(trace in colNames){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace)
}

p %>% 
  layout(title = "Trend Over Time",showlegend = FALSE,
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list (title = "Monthly Count of QoL Tweets"))
})
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
My apologies in advance for not being able to include reproducible data.

Comment: So your input data has 0 value? Couldn't that be removed with a `group_by` ```sum```?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand. group_by sum on the filtered dataset?

Comment: `Trace 0` is showing up because there are some months where you have got values 0 right?

Comment: Also could you please try this change? 
`mutate(Month=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))
})`

Comment: I get an Error: Column `Month` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 12 when I make that change

Comment: Yes I have values that are 0. Do you suggest that I replace the cells that contain 0 with empty?

Comment: The months are still displayed because you've got a factor, so either having character values for Month should fix this problem or alternatively you can try NA instead of 0s.

Comment: I tried NA instead of 0, still the same. When I double click on trace 0 in the legend, I see trace 0 values from the y axis. So these trace 0 values have nothing to do with the x-axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a problem with your approach.

Check this below reproducible code to fix yours.

```
df <- iris

p <- plotly::plot_ly()

colNames <- names(df)

colNames <- colNames[-which(colNames == 'Species')]


for(trace in colNames){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(data= df, x = ~ Species, y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace)

  print(paste0("~`", trace, "`"))

}

p
```

[image]

Ideally,  Your modified code should be something like this:

```
output$pg1evolution <- renderPlotly({

colNames <- names(global_evolution_final())[-1] #Assuming Month is the first column

p <- plotly::plot_ly()

for(trace in colNames){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(data = global_evolution_final(), x = ~Month, y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace, type = "bar")
}

p %>% 
  layout(title = "Trend Over Time",showlegend = FALSE,
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list (title = "Monthly Count of QoL Tweets"))
})
```